# Is there a limit for createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I am receiving a huge number of pictures over a websocket and just save the url I get from "createObjectURL" in an array to use these pictures later. Do anyone know, whether there is a limit to the number of URLs I created this way? Or will the limitation depends on how many URLs I can save in an array?

Comment: Do you have issues when you try it?

Comment: No, no issues till now, but in my test scenario I am sending only 500 images (at an resolution of 1080p).

Comment: I am asking, cause if someone could tell me the limit, I could plan ... you are right I could just sent infinite images and see, when it will crash but still this wouldnt be accurate. I guess I will figuiring it out. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Where's the fun in finding the limits by asking?  Go, break stuff, and be merry!

Comment: Did you find a limit? I wonder because I found IE making trouble with lots of createObjectURL calls.

Comment: @Prinzhorn No I did not, but I remember 500 image 226kb each was no problem for chrome, never ran into a limit. Chrome was caching them on HDD so I guessed the limit would be the availabe hdd cache of chrome.